# Upscaling and downscaling in ffmpeg using Lanczos and bicubic filters

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, yuv

I'm supposed to upscale and downscale a video sequence by a factor of 2 and 3 using Lanczos and Bicubic filter in ffmpeg. I want to know that what does it mean when it says factor 2 or 3? As I was searching couldn't find a command line for this one (written in factor). Would you please guide me in this regard?

Thanks

Comment: Upscale by factor of 3 would mean scale from 100x200 to 300x600.

Comment: … but would it? That's a factor of three by dimension, but nine by area. I'd try one & see what it does, tbh.